# Extending a scaffold build

Tags: gruntjs

I've built a bootstrap app with yeoman and grunt but now need to add another library(d3). I've downloaded d3 with bower and included the script tag and everything works in development. When I run a dist build the D3 lib doesn't show up in the dist folder and app returns errors because it cannot find the lib.

What's the best workflow to extend scaffold setups using grunt, bower and yeoman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

downloads and install the package :

```
bower install d3 --save
```

updates packages json

add all relvant packages to the project :

```
grunt bower-install
```

updaes index.html

Comment: Almost, the second line needed to be grunt bowerInstall. Otherwise now works, thanks.